# Picasso не хочет отображать картинки с первого раза, что не так?

Tags: android, picasso

Создаю в цикле динамически ImageView по списку ссылок на картинки. При первом запуске картинки не отображаются, при повторном запуске отображаются. В чем может быть дело и как исправить?

Такое ощущение что пока картинки грузятся, что то успевает заснуть, до того как отобразит картинки, а второй раз берет просто из кэша :/

```
for (int z = 0; z < zCont.length; z++) {

LinearLayout.LayoutParams params = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(100, 100);
                        params.gravity= Gravity.LEFT;
                        ImageView iv = new ImageView(this);
                        iv.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.FIT_XY);
                        setImage(iv, "http://sait.ru/fotota/foto"+tel+".jpeg");
                        linearLayout.addView(iv, params);
}

private void setImage(final ImageView imageView, final String imgURL) {
        Picasso.with(this)
                .load(imgURL)
                .error(R.mipmap.ic_launcher)
                .into(new Target() {
                    @Override public void onBitmapLoaded(Bitmap bitmap, Picasso.LoadedFrom from) {
                        Log.e("loaded", "onBitmapLoaded: loaded" );
                        imageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
                        imageView.invalidate();
                    }

                    @Override public void onBitmapFailed(Drawable errorDrawable) {
                        Log.e("loaded", "onBitmapFailed: load failed" );
                    }

                    @Override public void onPrepareLoad(Drawable placeHolderDrawable) {

                    }
                });
    }
```

Comment: Должно работать такое по идее. Попробуйте сначала добавить в разметку ImageView а потом запускать загрузку. Ну и не понятно завем Target используете. Попробуйте без него сразу в ImageView грузить

Comment: @ЮрийСПб Спасибо! Замена Target на ImageView действительно помогла, все стало грузится как надо. Дайте ответ, я отмечу его как лучший.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Попробуйте загружать картинку обычным способом без использования Target, т.е. как-то так:

```
Picasso.with(this)
        .load(imgURL)
        .error(R.mipmap.ic_launcher)
        .into(imageView);
```